# Building an Adjacency Matrix by assign 1 for element when its corresponding element in the same cluster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (df1, df2), df1 contains the list of topics and df2 contains the topics in df1 with its cluster or group.

Here is a sample input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'topics':['algebra', 'evolution', 'calculus', 'quantum', 'geometry', 'botany', 'physics', 'zoology']})
```

giving

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'topics':['algebra', 'calculus', 'geometry','evolution', 'botany', 'zoology', 'quantum', 'physics'],    
                    'cluster':[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
                   })
```

giving

[image]

From the above dataframes, I need to create a final dataframe as below which has a matrix structure, (e.g. if the corresponding topic in the same cluster, assign 1, and otherwise 0)?

[image]

Comment: Why is the 3rd cell (`calculus`) of the 1st row (`algebra`) 1?

Comment: @richardec they are rows of data for df1, each row and column represent the elements of df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution that works:

```
s = df2.set_index('topics')['cluster']
new_df = pd.concat([s.eq(s[k]) for k in df1['topics']], axis=1).loc[df1['topics'].tolist()].astype(int).set_axis(df1['topics'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
topics     algebra  evolution  calculus  quantum  geometry  botany  physics  zoology
topics                                                                              
algebra          1          0         1        0         1       0        0        0
evolution        0          1         0        0         0       1        0        1
calculus         1          0         1        0         1       0        0        0
quantum          0          0         0        1         0       0        1        0
geometry         1          0         1        0         1       0        0        0
botany           0          1         0        0         0       1        0        1
physics          0          0         0        1         0       0        1        0
zoology          0          1         0        0         0       1        0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.topics)
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    new_df[row.values[0]] = (df2.cluster == row.values[1]).astype(int).values
```